# Finding out the size of taskbar in Linux (C/C++/gtkmm/other)

Tags: c++, c, linux, user-interface, gtkmm

How can I find the effective working are of my Linux desktop (by which I mean: screen's height - taskbar's height)?

I need this for my program, which I am writing in c++/gtkmm. I want to position the window in the bottom-right corner of the screen, above the taskbar.

At first I tried to maximize the window, check its height and subtract it from screen's height. For some reason it gives me the height before the maximalization, so it doesn't work.

Comment: Bad idea assuming you know the position of the taskbar. I have seen this in other programs on windows that just kind of float because my taskbar isn't in the "expected" place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the `map-event` event before checking the size of your window.

Unlike what apmasell and senshikaze stated, you can quite reliably do this using GTK+.  However, you should connect to the relevant signals (`map-event`, `configure-event`, `screen-changed`, `visibility-notify-event` and maybe `window-state-event`), so your small window will correctly move/resize, when screen resolution or toolbars change.

For example, I personally use two auto-hidden bars on XFCE4. If there is a small tool window "docked" to the bottom right corner, I want it to move out of the way when my bottom bar is shown.

If the window is a pure notification window, then I agree with apmasell that you're best off using `libnotify` (for example, run `notify-send ...` as a child process) to generate a normal notification window.

As a proof of concept, here is a small C program, `size.c`, which obtains the information using a fully transparent undecorated window:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdk.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int screen_width = -1;
int screen_height = -1;

int window_left = -1;
int window_top = -1;
int window_width = -1;
int window_height = -1;

void done(GtkWidget *widget, void *payload)
{
    GdkScreen *screen = gtk_widget_get_screen(widget);

    screen_width = gdk_screen_get_width(screen);
    screen_height = gdk_screen_get_height(screen);

    gtk_window_get_position((GtkWindow *)widget, &window_left, &window_top);
    gtk_window_get_size((GtkWindow *)widget, &window_width, &window_height);

    gtk_widget_destroy(widget);
    gtk_main_quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_opacity((GtkWindow *)window, 0.0);
    gtk_window_set_decorated((GtkWindow *)window, (gboolean)FALSE);
    gtk_window_maximize((GtkWindow *)window);
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    g_signal_connect(window, "map-event", G_CALLBACK(done), NULL);
    gtk_main();

    if (screen_width > 0 && screen_height > 0)
        printf("Screen is %d x %d pixels\n", screen_width, screen_height);

    if (window_width > 0 && window_height > 0)
        printf("Window is %d x %d pixels\n", window_width, window_height);

    if (window_left > 0)
        printf("There is a %d pixel wide left bar\n", window_left);

    if (window_left >= 0 && window_width > 0 && screen_width > 0 && window_width + window_left < screen_width)
        printf("There is a %d pixel wide right bar\n", screen_width - (window_width + window_left));

    if (window_top > 0)
        printf("There is a %d pixel tall top bar\n", window_top);

    if (window_top >= 0 && window_height > 0 && screen_height > 0 && window_height + window_top < screen_height)
        printf("There is a %d pixel tall bottom bar\n", screen_height - (window_height + window_top));

    return 0;
}
```

Compile using

```
gcc -W -Wall size.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -o size
```

or, if still using GTK+ 2,

```
gcc -W -Wall size.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` -o size
```

Run using `./size`. Note that the test program only provides a snapshot; a real program should connect to the aforementioned signals to detect screen or toolbar changes, and update the window size/position accordingly.

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: That is pretty cool. I haven't found an app that does changes in the position of the taskbar (windows & *nix) well. It is nice knowing that gtk can do it (even if some devs are lazy)

Comment: Nominal Animal's answer is what I was looking for, thank you very much. To others suggesting libnotify - I know about this and in fact used it in the past. What I want to make is program that's a hybrid of tomboy-notes and "to do list" from igoogle, that stays open in selected area of the desktop (like top-left,right-bottom etc.) and minimizes to tray when requested.

Comment: shenshikaze: Yes, it is purely programmer laziness that apps do not react to toolbar changes. I have the same example code using Qt (PyQt4 to be exact), and it works just as well. Both GTK+ and Qt versions work with all window managers I've tested. @user1656791: I had a hunch you were doing something like that; that's why I posted my answer. The integration to desktop environments this way only needs a bit of effort from the programmer. Please make sure your code adapts to all four edges (like my example code shows), and does not assume anything; I'd love to see that behaviour in an app!

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that you can reliably determine this, especially if the user is not using the same desktop (e.g., KDE versus GNOME versus Unity). You are probably better off to use [libnotify](http://developer-next.gnome.org/libnotify/0.7/) to display a notification beside the taskbar. You can add buttons to the notification that trigger callbacks in your program.